# Understanding recursion

Tags: recursion

I am struggling to understand this recursion used in the dynamic programming example. Can anyone explain the working of this. The objective is to find the least number of coins for a value.

//**f(n) = 1 + min f(n-d)**  for all denomimations d

Pseudocode:

```
int memo[128]; //initialized to -1

int min_coin(int n)
{
   if(n < 0) return INF;
   if(n == 0) return 0;
   if(memo[n] != -1)

   int ans = INF;
   for(int i = 0; i < num_denomination; ++i)
   {
      ans = min(ans, min_coin(n - denominations[i]));
   }
   return memo[n] = ans+1; //when does this get called?

}
```

Comment: Some `{}` missing after `if(memo[n] != -1)` ?

Comment: I don't know to correct it. It was given as an example here http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs490/sec202/notes/dp/DP%201.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This particular example is explained very well in this [article](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg) at Topcoder.

Basically this recursion is **using the solutions to smaller problems** (least number of coins for a smaller n) **to find the solution for the overall problem**. The dynamic programming aspect of this is the [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of the solutions to the sub-problems so they don't have to be recalculated every time.

And yes - there are {} missing as ring0 mentioned in his comment - the recursion should only be executed if the sub-problem has not been solved before.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the owner's question *when does this get called?* : in a solution based on a recursive program, the same function is called by itself... but eventually returns... When does it return? from the time the function ceased to call itself

```
f(a) {
  if (a > 0) f(a-1);
  display "x" 
}

f(5);
```

`f(5)` would call f(4), in turns call f(3) that call f(2) which calls f(1) calling f(0).

`f(0)` has `a` being 0, so it does not call `f()`, and displays "x" then *returns*. It returns to the previous `f(1)` that, after calling `f(0)` - done - displays also "x". `f(1)` ends, f(2) displays "x", ... , until f(5). You get 6 "x".

Answer (score 0):

In another terms from what ring0 has already mentioned - when the program reaches the base case and starts to unwind by going up the stack (call frames).  For similar case using [factorial example see this.](http://www.hiregion.com/2013/02/recursion-defined.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env  perl

use strict;
use IO::Handle;
use Carp qw(cluck);

STDOUT->autoflush(1);
STDERR->autoflush(1);

sub factorial {
    my $v = shift;

    dummy_func();
    return 1 if $v == 1;
    print "Variable v value: $v and it's address:", \$v, "\ncurrent sub factorial addr:", \&factorial, "\n","-"x40;
    return $v * factorial($v - 1);
}

sub dummy_func {
    cluck;
}

factorial(5);
```